# Google App Engine Flexible - How can I list all files in the deployed application

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google App Engine Flexible and I intend to see all the files deployed for the current django application. How can I achieve this ?

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -t 3600 -b :$PORT project_name.wsgi

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: 'myapp:europe-west2:myapp'

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can SSH into one your App Engine Flexible service instances and start a shell in the container that is running your code.

[Here is the documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance) that shows how to do it.